# jQuery within a called modal

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a script where I call a modal window which consists of another .cfm page. My question is: When the script calls the .cfm is the jQuery scripts from the parent page recognized by the .cfm? It seems that I am getting zero response from jQuery. Here is the code within the .cfm:

```
<head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete-asset").click(function(){
   var delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'cfc/Assets.cfc?method=DeleteAsset&returnformat=json',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          argdelete_id: delete_id.val(),
        },
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING
        } else { // DO SOMETHING }
      }
    }
   });
 });
});
</script>

<cfparam name="url.uid" default="">

        <cfquery name="qPics">
        SELECT aq.Thumbs, aq.photos, aq.notes, a.assetID
        FROM tblAssetAssign a 
        INNER JOIN tblAssets aq ON aq.ID = a.Asset
        WHERE a.AssetItem = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#URL.uID#">                
        </cfquery>

</head>

<body>
     <div class="grid_6">
        <cfoutput query="qPics">
           <div class="block-pics">
               <img src="#site.URL#images/thumbs/#thumbs#" />
               <div class="note">#notes#</div>
               <div class="block-pics-remove"><a class="delete-asset" id="#assetID#"><img src="#site.URL#/assets/images/remove.png"></a></div>
           </div>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using jQuery-1.9.1.js & ColdFusion 9

Comment: What is the JSON output of the URL? Does any thing come in Firebug?

Comment: no... thats why I am kinda puzzled. I am getting zero response. Everything is working fine in the parent page.

Comment: Do you have any demo link? Did you tried to find anything the "NET" tab (XHR) in firebug? What output you get when you try www.site.com/cfc/Assets.cfc?method=DeleteAsset&returnformat=json directly in the browser

Comment: Okay... there was an error with the Assets.cfc so that is now corrected. I now get a proper response when going directly to the file as you recommended within the browser. {"SUCCESS":false,"ERRORS":[{"ERROR":"The ARGDELETE_ID parameter to the DeleteAsset function is required but was not passed in.","PROPERTY":""}],"DATA":""} which is correct. When trying to access it from the parent with the argdelete_ID parameter, I still receive no response within XHR or in the Console. I would suspect that I would get at least the same response that I got when I accessed the file directly. right?

Comment: Yes. You should be getting the same response in firebug that you got when accessing the link directly in browser.

Comment: That's what I suspected. The only response I get is the initial response for calling the .cfm into the modal. After that, when I click the anchor... there is no response.

Comment: Do you have any link for me to see that?

Comment: ummm... not really. This is proprietary with secure user access. I can give you a screen shot. What would you like me to simulate and show?

Comment: Oh.. ok.. I guess then someone wiht CF knowledge might come to help.

Comment: Thanks Purus. However I do not see the CF is an issue. There is no error once the Parameter's are met. I checked it with static values. I think it is a client side issue.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?  If so, please post your resolution as an answer so that it may help others.